# std::thread member function. Should class fields be accessed by this pointer?

Tags: c++, stdthread

Given a class such as:

```
class MyClass {
  private:
  vector<std::string> data;

  void threadWork(std::vector<std::string> *data_ptr) {
    // some thread work... e.g
    for(int i=0; i < data_ptr->size(); i++) {
       std::string next = (*data_ptr)[i];
       // do stuff
    }
  }

  void callThreadedFunc(int nthread) {
    std::vector<std::thread> tgroup;
    std::vector<std::string> data_ptr = &data;
    for(int i=0; i < nthreads; i++) {
     tgroup.push_back(std::thread(&myClass::threadWork, this, data_ptr));
    }
    for(auto &t : tgroup) {t.join();}
  }
}
```

`this`is required to be passed into the thread constructor. Does this mean I should be accessing all class fields that thread requires via `this` instead of by field specific pointers? 
For example, `threadWork()` should access `data` as follows:

```
void threadWork(MyClass *obj) {
// some thread work... e.g
  for(int i=0; i < obj->data.size(); i++) {
     std::string next = obj.data[i];
     // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `threadWork` is a member function and you properly create the thread using `this`, you can access all member variables of the instance normally, no need to pass a pointer or reference to the data.

Doing just

```
std::thread(&myClass::threadWork, this)
```

is enough, and then in the thread function you can use the member variables normally:

```
void threadWork(/* no argument */) {
    // some thread work... e.g
    for(int i=0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        std::string next = data[i];  // Uses the member variable "normally"
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: But passing in a pointer to a field is also valid? I actually have two different vectors, and to reduce duplicate code, pass in one of the two.

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak Of course you can pass anything you want as arguments  to the thread function, but if it's not going to access a member variable directly I would suggest you make the function `static` and then pass a pointer (or reference) to the data the function should work on instead of `this` when creating the thread.